# Output all translation strings to javascript object

Tags: localization

How can I output all translation strings to a javascript object?

Of course I could do it one by one like this:

```
<script>
translations.string = {{ "string" | t }};

...
</script>
```

But I want to just loop through all translation strings. Is there some kind of twig object containing all these strings?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. You would have to create a plugin that scrapes all of your template files for translatable strings, that then also makes those strings available to twig templates.